# angularJS, doing post-map-catch, but the catch function could not be found

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have already imported all the needed modules ahead like this:

```
import {Message} from "./message.model";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
```

the map function can be found, but not the catch function.
anyone has any ideas, please inform me, thanks ahead.
the code attached below and also can be found in the screenshot.
[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDR9s.png)

```
@Injectable
export class MessageService {

    private messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    addMessage (message: Message) {
        this.messages.push(message);
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        // return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message', body)
        //     .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        //     .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message', body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const result = response.json();
                const message = new Message(result.obj.content, 'Dummy', result.obj._id, null);
                this.messages.push(message);
                return message;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()))
    }

    getMessage () {
        return this.messages;
    }

    deleteMessage (message: Message) {
        this.messages.splice(this.messages.indexOf(message), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the operator, like this:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```